# How do I change the default version of Firefox using Selenium webdriver with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium

I was able to use the following code to change the Firefox version I am using to 33.1 successfully. But how can I make the current version the default without having to add this additional code to each script?

```
path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = path
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
```

I have converted Selenium IDE scripts to WebDriver using Ruby and it always defaults to Firefox 11. My computer's default version of Firefox is 33.1 and my current WebDriver version for  Ruby is 2.44.

Answer (score 0):

Point the webdriver firefix profile to existing default profile as below:

```
default_profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name "default"
default_profile.native_events = true
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, :profile => default_profile)
```

Refer [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using windows follow steps to set default profile, you can also search for equivalent process in case of any other OS, Following solution is purely non-programatic.

---

1) click start
2) type "run"
3) type "firefox.exe -p"
[image]

4) Press "ok"
then following dialog appears, select any Firefox profile according to your needs.
[image]

You can also create and delete profiles, and also load them by referring to their path or name.